# coloring a graph such that neighbors have distinct colors

Tags: graph-theory, terminology, coloring

Suppose I want a graph coloring with the additional property that no two neighbors of a a given vertex are the same color. Does this have a name?

Comment: Not sure about a name,  but you can transform to the usual vertex coloring problem by adding edges between all such pairs of neighbors.

Comment: ah, nice observation